Renormalization of the composite operator $\exp(\phi(x))$
I'd like to calculate $\langle\Omega|\exp(\phi(x))|\Omega\rangle$ for quartic scalar field theory (where $|\Omega\rangle$ is the interacting vacuum) and then renormalize to first order in the coupling constant. How do I go about renormalizing the composite operator $e^{\phi(x)}$? Sources exist detailing the renormalization of the composite operator $\phi^{2}(x)$, but I can't find anything for the case of a function of the field that is an infinite series (such as the exponential).

Do you have a reason to expect that there is a more efficient way of performing the calculation than developing the exponential series and computing term by term ?

Hi Jack. In how many spacetime dimensions? Is $\phi$ dimensionless so that $\exp(\phi)$ makes sense?
